# IndentLine vim plugin not working

Tags: vim

Hey so I'm having trouble getting IndentLine working and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong...I added both the entire directory to my bundle (because I use Pathogen) and the indentLine.vim script to my .vim folder directly with no luck. I'm on Vim 7.3, and here's my .vimrc

```
syntax on

set number
set mouse=a
set ruler
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set colorcolumn=100
set foldmethod=indent
set nofoldenable
set tags=./tags;
set background=light
set mouse=niv
set clipboard=unnamed

let g:tagbar_left = 0
let g:tagbar_autoshowtag = 0

"autocmd VimEnter * nested :call tagbar#autoopen(1)
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p

autocmd WinEnter * call s:CloseIfOnlyNerdTreeLeft()

" Close all open buffers on entering a window if the only
" buffer that's left is the NERDTree buffer
function! s:CloseIfOnlyNerdTreeLeft()
  if exists("t:NERDTreeBufName")
    if bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1
      if winnr("$") == 1
        q
      endif
    endif
  endif
endfunction

execute pathogen#infect()

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

noremap i l
noremap n h
noremap e j
noremap u k

noremap k n
noremap f s
noremap l {
noremap m }
noremap r m

noremap t u
noremap s i

inoremap <C-v> <C-r>"
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:w<CR>

nmap ^[> :vertical res +1^M
nmap ^[< :vertical res -1^M
nmap ^[+ :res +1^M
nmap ^[- :res -1^M

let g:indentLine_char = '│'
let g:indentLine_color_term = 000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: here's the link to the script on github https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine

Comment: If you're asking about a plugin it would be nice if you would link to the source of the plugin so those of us trying to help don't have to search.  This also tells us exactly which version of a plugin you are trying to use.

Comment: IndentLine's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine/issues).

Comment: Sorry about that; edited.
And I'm pretty sure this isn't a bug with their code, I think I'm just missing something simple (maybe a key to turn it on? but when I looked at that, it says it's on by default).

Comment: Check if the plugin is being loaded; if it is, it should appear on output of `:scriptnames`.

Comment: Yes indentLines is in the output of `:scriptnames`

Comment: I believe you're supposed to put `execute pathogen#infect()` at the very top of your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if the problem is in your configurations. You could comment all lines on your `.vimrc` and check if the plugin works; then remove all files from your `~/.vim` except the IndentLine plugin.

In case the plugin works, you can insert parts of your configuration until it stops working again, so you can understand what is broking it.

If you are unable to make the plugin work you should follow romainl advice and report to the plugin's author.

---

**Edit:**

From the plugin readme:

```
This plugin is used for displaying thin vertical lines at each indentation
level for code indented with spaces. For code indented with tabs I think there
is no need to support it, because you can use :set list lcs=tab:\|\ (here is a
space).
```

If you are using tabs for indent then the plugin will not work, so you will have to issue `:set expandtab` or leave that line uncommented on your `.vimrc`.

Try performing the following steps:

1. with a fresh new installation of Vim/gVim, create an empty file on your home and name it `.vimrc`
2. extract the downloaded plugin to home directory and renamed it to `.vim`
3. open gVim, issue `:set et`
4. enter the following text: if<kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>if<kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>return

If the plugin works, you should end with something like this:

```
if
        if
        |       return
```

, where the `|` is not typed, but inserted by the plugin.

Comment: Commented everything out, emptied .vim to just indentLine, and still no luck :( Guess I'll report to the author.

Comment: Yeah I left `set expandtab` in, but still no luck :/

Comment: @Californian: In this case you should report to the author.